# sort differently depending on # of values

Tags: oracle10g

I have

select title, COST, ORDERDATE
from customers C, books B, orders
where C.lastname='LUCAS'
AND C.firstname='JAKE'
order by ORDERDATE, cost DESC

but it has to be order by ORDERDATE if 1 item only, else order cost DESc

what changes does it need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one item and therefore only one orderdate then you don't need to order that result since there is only 1 row, it is already sorted in any order you want. Thus you can just use

```
ORDER BY cost DESC
```

It will always be sorted by cost.  This works for mutliple items and also a single item because ordering by cost doesn't matter for one row.

Perhaps though there is more to this query?